# BehaviorSubject: why is it working without using next

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have an Angular app and I created a class for my contact list which consists of:

```
export interface Contact {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    address: string;
}

export class ContactList {
    private contactList: Contact[];
    private contactNumber: number;

public getContactList(): Contact[] {
        return this.contactList;
    }

// Methods to add, modify and remove a contact
}
```

Then I have a service that instantiates this class, creates a *BehaviorSubject* to share it with other components and has some public methods.

```
export class ContactListService {

  public contactList: ContactList;
  private contactList$: BehaviorSubject<Contact[]>;

  constructor() {
    this.contactList = new ContactList(FAKE_CONTACTS);
    this.contactList$ = new BehaviorSubject<Contact[]>(this.contactList.getContactList());
  }

  public getContactList(): BehaviorSubject<Contact[]> {
    return this.contactList$;
  }

  public deleteContact(contactId: number): void {
    this.contactList.deleteContact(contactId);
  }

  public addContact(newName: string, newAddress: string): void {
    this.contactList.addContact(newName, newAddress);
  }

  public modifyContact(contactId: number, newName?: string, newAddress?: string): void {
    this.contactList.modifyContact(contactId, newName, newAddress);
  }
}
```

Then, in a component, I subscribe to the *BehaviorSubject* and affect the value to a property of my component.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.contactListSubscription = this.contactListService.getContactList().subscribe((newContactList) => {
      this.contactList = newContactList;
    });
  }
```

So it's working (ie. everything is update everywhere when I perform an action via the service). But what I don't understand is that the content of the subscription (ie. `this.contactList = newContactList`) is only performed one time at the subscription and not every time an action occurs. Even if I change the content via a contactListService method. And even if I unsubscribe, like 2s after subscribing (with a setTimeout for example), the content is always up to date after the unsubscribing...

At first, I even didn't understood why it works in the services without doing a `contactList$.next(this.contactList.getContactList())` after every actions that modify the object.

So it seems like I passed some references instead of the content of the class? I think I don't understand how *BehaviorSubject* works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript **always** passes references to objects.

So the `contactList` array in the component is a reference to the same, unique array stored in your `ContactList.contactList` property.

So, you modify the array, the component has a reference to this modified array, and Angular detects the changes in the array, and applies the changes to the DOM.

It wouldn't work anymore if the methods in `ContactList` replaced the array by another one (a modified copy), i.e. did, for example

```
this.contactList = [this.contactList..., newContact]
```

In that case, the component would keep referencing the previous, unmodified array.

To illustrate with code:

```
service.contactList = ['John', 'Mary'];
component.contactList = service.contactList; // the exact, same array

service.contactList.push('Helen'); // add an element to the unique array
console.log(component.contactList); // logs John, Mary, Helen: it's the same, unique array

service.contactList = ['Jack']; // now the service references a second, different array
console.log(component.contactList); // Still logs John, Mary, Helen
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, here the *BehaviorSubject* is doing nothing at all! I'm only passing references through them. So how could I achieve a correct way of doing this (ie. passing the value of the service contactList, not its reference)? Is this a problem because in my example, only the service is allowed to modify the content of this instance of contactList?

Comment: You return a copy of the array from getContactList(), to make sure the internal array stays unmodifiable outside of the ContactList class: `return [...this.contactList];`. Note that this will still make every contact inside the array modifiable from everywhere if they're mutable: the array contains **references** to objects.

Comment: Ok! I already experienced this problem in a Java project, I understand that the behaviour here is the same. So to improve my code, I should pass (as you wrote) a copy of the array and call `next` on contactList$ after every modification in my service to notify every component that is subscribing that the object was updated! Thank you